# Get specific value from datasnapshot

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have users database, where every user is given a random id. Each user has data which I want to get its value. Sometimes I want only 1 specific user and sometimes I want all of the users' data. The database looks like this:

```
database
   |
   |__users
        |____uid1
              |_____dataKey1: value1
              |_____dataKey2: value2
              |_____dataKey3: value3
```

If I only need the value1 of dataKey1, how to get it? Currently my code returns a map of all the uid1 children:

```
    DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference ref= rootRef.child("users").child("uid1");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                value= ds.getValue().toString();
                Log.d("TAG", values);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    imageNamesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

in the log I get:

```
TAG: value1
TAG: value2
TAG: value3
```

but I want:

```
TAG: value1
```

Where do I filter out the keys that I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref= rootRef.child("users").child("uid1");
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      String value = dataSnapshot.child("dataKey1").getValue().toString();
      Log.d("TAG", value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
imageNamesRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

You have access to child `uid1`, therefore to get the value of `dataKey1` you do not need to loop.